# Justified image gallery with polymer

Tags: polymer, image-gallery

is there a way to use [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) or other similar plugin with Polymer?

I tried to use it but it won't find images because of the template.
My polymer element:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
        <a href="{{post.image}}" title="{{post.title}}">
            <img alt="{{post.title}}" src="{{post.image}}" />
        </a>
    </template>
</div>

<script>
    Polymer({
        domReady: function() {
            $(this.$.gallery).justifiedGallery();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you can encapsulate this jquery plugin into it's own Polymer element.

Comment: This is a polymer element, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: I can see that this is a Polymer element, but I don't see that it is encapsuling jquery gallery plugin. Is it?

Comment: Is there something more to do than calling justifiedGallery() on the div when DOM is ready?

Comment: Oh... I see, you are trying to incapsulate it. Well, first of all I think that you can't reference jquery with $ in Polymer element, because it's reserved already. Once you will fix this, It probably should work. Not sure about existence of 'domReady' function in Polymer also.

Comment: The function gets called...

Answer (score 0):

Use Polymer not JQuery! You have aproprieate guide (GitHub also)
[here](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-image-gallery-component-with-polymer/)

For layout images in gallery (stretch, center and more) use Polymer [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)